# Why does reducing the n_estimators in RandomForestClassifier improve accuracy?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest

I am taking a course that introduced me to sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier. At first it uses `n_estimators` with the default value of 10 and the resulting accuracy turns out to be around 0.28. If I change `n_estimators` to 15, the accuracy goes to 0.32

Here's some of the code:

```
pl = Pipeline([
        ('union', FeatureUnion(
            transformer_list = [
                ('numeric_features', Pipeline([
                    ('selector', get_numeric_data),
                    ('imputer', Imputer())
                ])),
                ('text_features', Pipeline([
                    ('selector', get_text_data),
                    ('vectorizer', CountVectorizer())
                ]))
             ]
        )),
        ('clf', RandomForestClassifier())
    ])
```

I thought that increasing the number of trees (`n_estimators`) in the RandomForestClassifier would give a better accuracy, but sometimes if I use a value of 100 I can get between 0.30 and 0.32. Could someone please explain? How do you find which is the smallest value for getting the highest possible accuracy?

Comment: There is no `n_elements` argument in sklearn's [RandomForestClassifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html); if you mean `n_estimators`, this has a default value of 100, and not 10. Please **clarify**, as your shown code is actually irrelevant to the question.

Comment: I just noticed I typed n_elements instead of n_estimators, sorry about that. I am taking a course in DataCamp called _Case Study: School Budgeting with Machine Learning in Python_ that specifies it has 10 as default (even though in the documentation 100 is specified for the default)

Comment: As can be seen in the documentation, the default was changed in version 0.22 from 10 to 100.

Comment: The only consistent effect of `n_estimators` is that more trees reduces variance in the predictions (and takes more time to train).  Any other apparent effect on performance is only due to random effects.  https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/1028/55122

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about testing accuracy in this case (ie you are comparing results on data you didn't train with) - it's possible that adding more estimators is overfitting on your training set and is therefore performing poorly on your holdout set. If this is the case I would recommend approaching the problem with a more basic method such as LogisticRegression - as it is less likely to overfit when compared to ensemble methods.

As for finding the best parameters - try sklearn's RandomizedSearchCV to fine-tune your hyperparameters to maximize performance.